# ResultSet search Error in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, resultset

so I am a beginer in *JDBC - SQL Programming*. I need a little advice which is most probably about SYNTAX.

So, **Problem** = I'm trying to search a record which has name(string provided in function argument) in the record. Following is my code. Now I've designed this code in such a way that there can be more than 1 records with the same name, so all of that records' data will be printed (by ShowData() Function).

```
protected static void SearchbyName (String toCompareName)
{
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    boolean flag = false;     //to confirm if record has found atleast once

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);    
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT idEmployee FROM employee WHERE name = ' "+toCompareName+" ' ");

        if( !(rs.next()) )    //if ResultSet is not empty
        {   
            while(rs.next())  //reading all records with the same name, extracted by Query
            {
                int foundID = rs.getInt("idEmployee");  //extracting ID of found record
                ShowRecord(foundID);        //prints record of foundID fromDB

                flag = true; //set flag
            }
        }
        if(flag==false) //if no record found
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR:: No Records Found..", "Not Found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        //close connection
        if(rs!=null)
        {   rs.close();     }
        if(stmt!=null)
        {   stmt.close();   }
        if(conn!=null)
        {   conn.close();       }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {   System.err.println(e);  }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   System.err.println(e);  }   

}
```

So here it is. As far as my understanding goes, there is some problem with either ***RESULTSET rs*** or the ***Query*** I'm executing.
Kindly help. & if you can suggest a better approach for search, sure do please. I'm going to write 4 more functions *SearchbyAge, SearchbyQualification, SearchbySpecialization* on the same pattern.

Comment: But you forgot to mention what is the error :)

Comment: You could also have errors in your show data function.  I would print out the query to std out.  You can then copy and past it in a database window, and see if it works.

Comment: @PeteBelford: No use Sir for this approach. I've tested my ShowData() function & it works 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOVLED**

My error was in query. I was putting spaces in string's syntax which I was comparing.

**WRONG** = `"(.. WHERE name = " ' +toCompareName+ '" ");

**RIGHT** = `"(.. WHERE name = "'+toCompareName+'" ");

So thats it. Hope it helps to anyone else. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just this is enough

```
 while(rs.next())  //reading all records with the same name, extracted by Query
            {
                int foundID = rs.getInt("idEmployee");  //extracting ID of found record
                ShowRecord(foundID);        //prints record of foundID fromDB

                flag = true; //set flag
            }
```

You don't have to check the data in resultset this way with a `if` case

```
if( !(rs.next()) )
```

This will move to the next record in the `resultset`

Comment: No use. I've added a `system.out.print("In while loop");` but it seems that control is not entering into this loop.